# No value given for one or more required parameters error in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, gridview

Am getting error while loading form there I bind table to gridview. Am getting error in this line

```
// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'invoiceDataSet.PurchaseOrder_1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.purchaseOrder_1TableAdapter.Fill(this.invoiceDataSet.PurchaseOrder_1);
```

Whats is my mistake ??

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: Impossible to say. You need to give much more information. What is the exact error? Where is your db initalization code? Where your gridview binding code? etc.

Comment: Sorry am new to C#, what it mean ?

Comment: check the this.purchaseOrder_1TableAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText. 
There may be a parameter used in the Query and you havent supplied it.

Comment: I didn't get the question please give more information..

Comment: Thankyou guys I solved it by delete table in dataset and again add the same table to dataset.

Comment: What was the problem? - You yourself can give an answer to your own question if it would be helpful for others.

Comment: Don't know exactly but I think problem in adding table to dataset. Because I try to preview the data's in particular table it show error like "Some values are missing" like so I just delete that table and add new table to dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what was the problem. But I solved it by deleting the table from dataset and add new table to dataset.